# PHP Regex to match a URL pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to build a regex in PHP so that

- `/test/randomstring1/randomstring2` matches
- `/test/randomstring1/randomstring2/` matches
- `/test/randomstring1/randomstring2/randomstring3` does not match

I've come up with

```
/test\/(.+?)\/.*[^\/]/
```

It works fine for the 2 first cases but the third also matches.
Could someone help me to figure out the thing that I am missing? 
Thanks!

Comment: You need `'~^/test/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$~'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `.` matches any char but line break chars. `.*` will match as many chars other than line break chars as possible.

You may use

```
preg_match('~^/test/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$~', $text, $matches)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v8BlQ7/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `/test/` - a literal substring
- `([^/]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than `/`
- `/` - a `/` char
- `([^/]+)` - Group 2: any one or more chars other than `/`
- `/?` - an optional `/`
- `$` - end of string.